# XHR теряет заголовки после смены роута | React

Tags: reactjs, xhr

У меня на сайте есть роутинг. Неожиданно открыл для себя такую проблему: Если у тебя медленный интернет Slow 3G, то запрос теряет свои заголовки после ответа.

Я был на роуте /home, после этого сделал запрос при медленном интернете, далее перешел на роут /home/xxx, и в этот момент мне возвращается запрос. Проблема в том, что в нем нет заголовков, которые я указал ранее (Token), а без него приходит ответ 401.

Пробовал менять Referrer Policy через meta, но не помогает.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.zzz.com/getUsers', true);
xhr.responseType = 'json'
xhr.setRequestHeader('Token', String(this.token));
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send(null);
```

**Если роут не менять, то это запрос проходит без ошибок.**

Comment: Проблема решилась после перевода с xhr на fetch. Не знаю, в чем причина подобного поведения, поэтому вопрос пока закрывать не буду.